# JSF Trinidad selectOneChoice UI COmponent

Tags: java, jsf, trinidad

This is my .xhtml file

```
<tr:selectOneChoice >
   <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}"/>
</tr:selectOneChoice>
```

I want to be able to identify between the different options in the client side.
In my backing bean I have boolean for each Choice.

Is it possible to actually identify between this options in the client side ?

The bean code goes like this :

```
public List<SelectItem> getItems(Menu menu) {
    List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList();
    SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem(new MyObj("some string",false), "label");
    list.add(selectItem);
    return list;
}
```

MyObj class contains the flag that I want to be able to see in the client side.

any one know how to do that ?

thanks ,

John.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a `List` of `MyObj`, iterate through the list and use the `itemDisabled` attribute on `f:selectItem`.

```
<tr:selectOneChoice>
  <tr:forEach items="#{bean.myObjList}" var="myObj">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{myObj.label}"
                  itemValue="#{myObj.value}"
                  itemDisabled="#{myObj.flag}"/>
  </tr:forEach>
</tr:selectOneChoice>
```

Comment: I don't want disabled items. I just want that some of the items will contains some boolean from the server and I will be able to see it on the client -> then when the user clicks on one item - I want on the client to be able to take from the event that fired also this boolean so I could check if the item has 'true' and do something..

Comment: Can't you just do that using a value change listener?